# curl not downloading the desired files

Tags: centos

I can't download the bash script for GitLab. Although, I can open the link in the browser.

How can I solve this?

```
[root@localhost ~]# curl https://packages.gitlab.com/install/repositories/gitlab/gitlab-ee/script.rpm.sh | sudo bash
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:39 --:--:--     0
```

Is it network related issue?

Edit:

```
[root@localhost ~]# curl -v https://packages.gitlab.com/install/repositories/gitlab/gitlab-ee/script.rpm.sh | sudo bash
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* About to connect() to packages.gitlab.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 54.153.54.194...
* Connected to packages.gitlab.com (54.153.54.194) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:02:00 --:--:--     0* NSS error -5961 (PR_CONNECT_RESET_ERROR)
* TCP connection reset by peer
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:02:01 --:--:--     0
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) TCP connection reset by peer
```

Edit-2:

```
[root@localhost ~]# openssl s_client -connect packages.gitlab.com:443 -state -nbio
CONNECTED(00000003)
turning on non blocking io
SSL_connect:before/connect initialization
SSL_connect:SSLv2/v3 write client hello A
SSL_connect:error in SSLv2/v3 read server hello A
write R BLOCK
^C
[root@localhost ~]#
```

Edit-3:

```
[root@localhost ~]# wget  https://packages.gitlab.com/install/repositories/gitlab/gitlab-ee/script.rpm.sh | sudo bash
--2018-08-31 06:09:29--  https://packages.gitlab.com/install/repositories/gitlab/gitlab-ee/script.rpm.sh
Resolving packages.gitlab.com (packages.gitlab.com)... 54.153.54.194
Connecting to packages.gitlab.com (packages.gitlab.com)|54.153.54.194|:443... connected.
^C
[root@localhost ~]# clock
Fri 31 Aug 2018 06:13:51 AM EDT  -0.850009 seconds
```

Edit-4:

```
 [root@localhost ~]# curl -v --tlsv1 https://packages.gitlab.com/install/repositories/gitlab/gitlab-ee/script.rpm.sh | sudo bash
   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
   0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* About to connect() to packages.gitlab.com port 443 (#0)
 *   Trying 54.153.54.194...
 * Connected to packages.gitlab.com (54.153.54.194) port 443 (#0)
 * Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
 *   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
   CApath: none
   0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:02:00 --:--:--     0* NSS error -5961 (PR_CONNECT_RESET_ERROR)
 * TCP connection reset by peer
   0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:02:01 --:--:--     0
 * Closing connection 0
 curl: (35) TCP connection reset by peer
 [root@localhost ~]# curl -v --tlsv1.1 https://packages.gitlab.com/install/repositories/gitlab/gitlab-ee/script.rpm.sh | sudo bash
   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
   0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* About to connect() to packages.gitlab.com port 443 (#0)
 *   Trying 54.153.54.194...
 * Connected to packages.gitlab.com (54.153.54.194) port 443 (#0)
 * Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
 *   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
   CApath: none
   0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:02:00 --:--:--     0* NSS error -5961 (PR_CONNECT_RESET_ERROR)
 * TCP connection reset by peer
   0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:02:01 --:--:--     0
 * Closing connection 0
 curl: (35) TCP connection reset by peer
 [root@localhost ~]# curl -v --tlsv1.2 https://packages.gitlab.com/install/repositories/gitlab/gitlab-ee/script.rpm.sh | sudo bash
   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
   0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* About to connect() to packages.gitlab.com port 443 (#0)
 *   Trying 54.153.54.194...
 * Connected to packages.gitlab.com (54.153.54.194) port 443 (#0)
 * Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
 *   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
   CApath: none
   0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:02:00 --:--:--     0* NSS error -5961 (PR_CONNECT_RESET_ERROR)
 * TCP connection reset by peer
   0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:02:01 --:--:--     0
 * Closing connection 0
 curl: (35) TCP connection reset by peer
 [root@localhost ~]#
```

Comment: It seems like a network issue (I can download the file with curl). Please post the verbose output of curl: `curl -v https://...`

Comment: Not a network issue atleast not at layer 3. Please find above in edit section.

Comment: Ok it seems to be an ssl error. Can you provide the output of: `openssl s_client -connect packages.gitlab.com:443 -state -nbio`

Comment: updated. Please advise man. I am facing this issue on windows platform as well.

Comment: out of interest, are you able to `wget` the .sh file instead? I wonder if it's an issue with your `curl ` package (albeit admittedly unlikely)

Comment: I believe you need to specify servername in your s_client test (ie. packages.gitlab.com again).

Comment: Updated with wget response as well.
Gerard, I am kinda noob. Please can you mention how to specify servername in my s_client test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the identified issue was related to MSS/MTU.
I needed to adjust the mss value to 1452 at router to fix this. All users/servers don't have this issue now.

Answer (score 0):

The point is Gitlab does not support sslv2 and sslv3 anymoe (See the [Qualys SSL checker report](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=packages.gitlab.com) of Gitlab under Configuration > Protocols). Your version of curl, openssl and wget try to connect to the server with outdated protocols.

In case of `curl` you might force the client to use TLS instead. Try the following options:

```
--tlsv1
--tlsv1.1
--tlsv1.2
--sslv2 # this will not work on Gitlab
--sslv3 # this will not work on Gitlab
```

I assume your operating system is old or outdated. You should update your system.

Comment: didn't work on --tlsv1, --tlsv1.1 and tlsv1.2. Please advise.
Find new response in Edit-4.

Comment: The 'SSLv23' internal function names and related state and error decodes in OpenSSL through 1.0.2 are a historical relic and do not indicate actual use or even attempted use of (obsolete) pre-TLS protocols. OpenSSL 1.1.0+ finally cleans this up.